# How to vectorize Pandas comparison between 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to apply various filters to a pandas df. Instead of looping through each row (I'm doing that now and it's unacceptably slow) I would like to apply vector operations if possible. However, some of the filters are not very simple.

```
productids = [
    '01t0J00000HcoqpQAB', '01t0J00000HcoqnQAB', '01t0J00000HcoqyQAB',
    '01t0J00000Hcor3QAB', '01t0J00000Hcor5QAB', '01t0J00000Hcor6QAB',
    '01t0J00000Hcor9QAB', '01t0J00000HcorCQAR', '01t0J00000HcorGQAR',
    '01t0J00000IDGAOQA5'
]

previous_products = [
{'01t0J00000Hcor3QAB', '01t0J00000IDGAOQA5', '01t0J00000Hcor5QAB', '01t0J00000HcoqyQAB', '01t0J00000Hcor9QAB', '01t0J00000HcorGQAR', '01t0J00000Hcor6QAB', '01t0J00000HcorCQAR', '01t0J00000HcoqnQAB'},
{'01t0J00000Hcor3QAB', '01t0J00000IDGAOQA5', '01t0J00000Hcor5QAB', '01t0J00000HcoqyQAB', '01t0J00000Hcor9QAB', '01t0J00000HcorGQAR', '01t0J00000Hcor6QAB', '01t0J00000HcorCQAR', '01t0J00000HcoqnQAB'},
{'01t0J00000Hcor3QAB', '01t0J00000IDGAOQA5', '01t0J00000Hcor5QAB', '01t0J00000HcoqyQAB', '01t0J00000Hcor9QAB', '01t0J00000HcorGQAR', '01t0J00000Hcor6QAB', '01t0J00000HcorCQAR', '01t0J00000HcoqnQAB'},
{'01t0J00000Hcor3QAB', '01t0J00000IDGAOQA5', '01t0J00000Hcor5QAB', '01t0J00000HcoqyQAB', '01t0J00000Hcor9QAB', '01t0J00000HcorGQAR', '01t0J00000Hcor6QAB', '01t0J00000HcorCQAR', '01t0J00000HcoqnQAB'},
{'01t0J00000Hcor3QAB', '01t0J00000IDGAOQA5', '01t0J00000Hcor5QAB', '01t0J00000HcoqyQAB', '01t0J00000Hcor9QAB', '01t0J00000HcorGQAR', '01t0J00000Hcor6QAB', '01t0J00000HcorCQAR', '01t0J00000HcoqnQAB'},
{'01t0J00000Hcor3QAB', '01t0J00000IDGAOQA5', '01t0J00000Hcor5QAB', '01t0J00000HcoqyQAB', '01t0J00000Hcor9QAB', '01t0J00000HcorGQAR', '01t0J00000Hcor6QAB', '01t0J00000HcorCQAR', '01t0J00000HcoqnQAB'},
{'01t0J00000Hcor3QAB', '01t0J00000IDGAOQA5', '01t0J00000Hcor5QAB', '01t0J00000HcoqyQAB', '01t0J00000Hcor9QAB', '01t0J00000HcorGQAR', '01t0J00000Hcor6QAB', '01t0J00000HcorCQAR', '01t0J00000HcoqnQAB'},
{'01t0J00000Hcor3QAB', '01t0J00000IDGAOQA5', '01t0J00000Hcor5QAB', '01t0J00000HcoqyQAB', '01t0J00000Hcor9QAB', '01t0J00000HcorGQAR', '01t0J00000Hcor6QAB', '01t0J00000HcorCQAR', '01t0J00000HcoqnQAB'},
{'01t0J00000Hcor3QAB', '01t0J00000IDGAOQA5', '01t0J00000Hcor5QAB', '01t0J00000HcoqyQAB', '01t0J00000Hcor9QAB', '01t0J00000HcorGQAR', '01t0J00000Hcor6QAB', '01t0J00000HcorCQAR', '01t0J00000HcoqnQAB'},
{'01t0J00000Hcor3QAB', '01t0J00000IDGAOQA5', '01t0J00000Hcor5QAB', '01t0J00000HcoqyQAB', '01t0J00000Hcor9QAB', '01t0J00000HcorGQAR', '01t0J00000Hcor6QAB', '01t0J00000HcorCQAR', '01t0J00000HcoqnQAB'}
]

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'productids': productids, 'previous_products': previous_products}, index=range(len(productids)))

df_test
```

Here's the filter that I am trying to apply:

`df_test.productids.isin(test.previous_products)`

The logic behind this is that I need to know if the id on the column 1 exists inside the ids set on column 2. Column 2 is the result of other set of functions to compute the previous products for each client. What I am doing now looks somewhat like this:

```
for i, row in df_test.iterrows():
    if row['productids'] in row['previous_products']:
        **do more stuff**
    else:
        **do different stuff**
```

The problem with that is that as the df get's larger, it takes a really long time to complete the loop.

Any other suggestions to go around this?

Comment: The problem lies with **do more stuff** and **do different stuff**.  Your answer likely depends on what **stuff** is.

Comment: otherwise `from operator import contains; [*map(contains, df_test.previous_products, df_test.productids)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]), columns=['col1','col2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1,2], columns = ['lookup_col'])

df_merge = df1.merge(df2, left_on='col1', right_on='lookup_col')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; although I am not sure I understand how your implementation would solve my issue.

Comment: It returns only those rows in df1 that have a matching record in df2, using the pandas merge function.  run df_merge = df_test.merge(test, left_on='productids', right_on='previous_products') and look at what is returned - it's the subset of rows you want to do stuff to, and then you can vectorise like normal